# Can you break my arrow non-shortening code?

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-arrows

I know that we frown on *code review*, so I'm trying to make this about the outcome rather than the method.

**The Problem I'm trying to solve**: My [`spath3`](https://ctan.org/pkg/spath3) provides the facility to save a TikZ path after it has been defined.  The goal is that the saved path should be the same as would have been drawn, so any styles that change the actual shape of the path should be applied prior to it being saved.  Then when the path is used, only those styles that affect its rendering should be applied.  The difficulty is with arrows: the arrow *itself* is style so shouldn't be applied when the path is saved, but the placement of the arrow changes the path so should.  Ideally, then, I need to separate the *rendering* of the arrow from its *placement*.  Unfortunately, the code that deals with the shortening of the path is buried very deep in the PGF core making it hard to access.

I have some code that purports to solve this.  It works by adjusting the various lengths involved with an arrow, effectively removing the length that controls the path shortening (it's slightly complicated due to *which* lengths of the arrow definition are stored).  But I need a test suite, so that's really what I'm asking for here.

Here's some code to play with:

```
\documentclass{article}
%\url{}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  spath3,
  arrows.meta
}

\makeatletter

\let\spath@orig@pgf@arrow@compute@shortening=\pgf@arrow@compute@shortening

% After \pgf@arrow@compute@shortening then \pgf@xa is the amount to
% shorten the line by, so we will be setting that to 0pt; while
% \pgf@xb is the length of the arrow head so is used to position the
% arrow and so before zeroing \pgf@xa we subtract it from \pgf@xb so
% that the arrow is placed so that its back point is at the current
% position.
\def\spath@arrow@compute@shortening#1{%
  \spath@orig@pgf@arrow@compute@shortening{#1}%
  \advance\pgf@xb by -\pgf@xa%
  \pgf@xa0pt%
}

\tikzset{
  spath/disable arrow shortening/.code={%
    \let\pgf@arrow@compute@shortening=\spath@arrow@compute@shortening
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex, line width=5pt]
% Just a simple line
\draw (0,1) -- +(5,0);
% Same line but with arrows, also save the path
\draw[->.>, spath/save=arrow] (0,0) -- +(5,0);
% Let's redraw that path without the arrows - it's short!
\draw[spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-1cm}}];
% So if we redraw it with arrows it gets doubly shortened
\draw[->.>,spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-2cm}}];
% If we disable the shortening, the arrows end up in the right place
\draw[->.>,spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-3cm}}, spath/disable arrow shortening];
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex, line width=5pt]
% Just a simple line
\draw (0,1) to[bend left] +(5,0);
% Same line but with arrows, also save the path
\draw[->.>, spath/save=arrow] (0,0) to[bend left] +(5,0);
% Let's redraw that path without the arrows - it's short! But also distorted
\draw[spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-1cm}}];
% So if we redraw it with arrows it gets doubly shortened
\draw[->.>,spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-2cm}}];
% If we disable the shortening, the arrows end up in the right place
\draw[->.>,spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-3cm}}, spath/disable arrow shortening];
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document}
```

This produces:

[image: Paths with arrows, both shortened and not shortened]

What I'm asking for is examples of paths where the second and last paths (the ones with the arrows) in a set are **not** the same.

Comment: I use the `spath/` prefix because it will be part of the `spath3` package.  I don't like polluting the main namespace.  Your example is an interesting one - the arrow shortening is so extreme that the end point of the path is _before_ its starting point, yet somehow the arrow "remembers" the direction of the end of the path.  I'll have to look into that to see how that is done.  Please consider posting that as an answer!

Comment: I misunderstood what you were referring to - sorry about that. i've fixed my code in the above. Thank you!

Comment: You can fix the distortion at the end by loading the `bending` library. (In the case in your question above.)

Comment: `\draw[->.>, spath/save=arrow] (0,0)   [out=90,in=-45] to +(5,0);` -> path gets lengthened and doubly lengthened, possibly.

Comment: @cfr While the `bending` library can help in certain situations, it can also distrort things in others. Your example does get rendered the same way, if `bending` is not loaded.

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes, I know. That's why I only said it amended the distortion in this case. Not sure what you mean about the example. I didn't have `bending` loaded then.

Comment: @cfr I mean that I get the same output for the second and the last path with `\draw[->.>, spath/save=arrow] (0,0) [out=90,in=-45] to +(5,0);`. But maybe I did not get your comment ...

Comment: @JasperHabicht Yes .... All I meant was that the distortion in the other cases is different. I'm not sure if the path is actually longer. I think it might just be straightened. The problem isn't a shortened or doubly shortened result. Maybe I misunderstand the question and the only concern is whether the second and last cases tally. That's not how I understood it, but that might just be because I was interested in the other cases for reasons of my own ....

Answer (score 4):

For very short paths where the path itself is shorter than the arrow tip, the code will break. The arrow tip will be turned to the other direction:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  spath3,
  arrows.meta
}

\makeatletter

\let\spath@orig@pgf@arrow@compute@shortening=\pgf@arrow@compute@shortening

% After \pgf@arrow@compute@shortening then \pgf@xa is the amount to
% shorten the line by, so we will be setting that to 0pt; while
% \pgf@xb is the length of the arrow head so is used to position the
% arrow and so before zeroing \pgf@xa we subtract it from \pgf@xb so
% that the arrow is placed so that its back point is at the current
% position.
\def\spath@arrow@compute@shortening#1{%
  \spath@orig@pgf@arrow@compute@shortening{#1}%
  \advance\pgf@xb by -\pgf@xa%
  \pgf@xa0pt%
}

\tikzset{
  spath/disable arrow shortening/.code={%
    \let\pgf@arrow@compute@shortening=\spath@arrow@compute@shortening
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex, line width=5pt]
% Just a simple line
\draw (0,1) -- ++(1,0);
% Same line but with arrows, also save the path
\draw[->.>, spath/save=arrow] (0,0) -- +(1,0);
% Let's redraw that path without the arrows - it's short! But also distorted
\draw[spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-1cm}}];
% So if we redraw it with arrows it gets doubly shortened
\draw[->.>,spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-2cm}}];
% If we disable the shortening, the arrows end up in the right place
\draw[->.>,spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-3cm}}, spath/disable arrow shortening];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

This is also relevant for paths that consist of segments where the last segment is very short which is typically the case with `plot`:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  spath3,
  arrows.meta
}

\makeatletter

\let\spath@orig@pgf@arrow@compute@shortening=\pgf@arrow@compute@shortening

% After \pgf@arrow@compute@shortening then \pgf@xa is the amount to
% shorten the line by, so we will be setting that to 0pt; while
% \pgf@xb is the length of the arrow head so is used to position the
% arrow and so before zeroing \pgf@xa we subtract it from \pgf@xb so
% that the arrow is placed so that its back point is at the current
% position.
\def\spath@arrow@compute@shortening#1{%
  \spath@orig@pgf@arrow@compute@shortening{#1}%
  \advance\pgf@xb by -\pgf@xa%
  \pgf@xa0pt%
}

\tikzset{
  spath/disable arrow shortening/.code={%
    \let\pgf@arrow@compute@shortening=\spath@arrow@compute@shortening
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex, line width=5pt]
% Just a simple line
\draw (0,1) plot (\x,1);
% Same line but with arrows, also save the path
\draw[->.>, spath/save=arrow] (0,0) plot (\x,0);
% Let's redraw that path without the arrows - it's short! But also distorted
\draw[spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-1cm}}];
% So if we redraw it with arrows it gets doubly shortened
\draw[->.>,spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-2cm}}];
% If we disable the shortening, the arrows end up in the right place
\draw[->.>,spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-3cm}}, spath/disable arrow shortening];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another variation that probably also fits here:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{
  spath3,
  arrows.meta
}

\makeatletter

\let\spath@orig@pgf@arrow@compute@shortening=\pgf@arrow@compute@shortening

% After \pgf@arrow@compute@shortening then \pgf@xa is the amount to
% shorten the line by, so we will be setting that to 0pt; while
% \pgf@xb is the length of the arrow head so is used to position the
% arrow and so before zeroing \pgf@xa we subtract it from \pgf@xb so
% that the arrow is placed so that its back point is at the current
% position.
\def\spath@arrow@compute@shortening#1{%
  \spath@orig@pgf@arrow@compute@shortening{#1}%
  \advance\pgf@xb by -\pgf@xa%
  \pgf@xa0pt%
}

\tikzset{
  spath/disable arrow shortening/.code={%
    \let\pgf@arrow@compute@shortening=\spath@arrow@compute@shortening
  }
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[>=Latex, line width=5pt]
% Just a simple line
\draw (0,1) arc[start angle=270, end angle=300, radius=8];
% Same line but with arrows, also save the path
\draw[->.>, spath/save=arrow] (0,0) arc[start angle=270, end angle=300, radius=8];
% Let's redraw that path without the arrows - it's short! But also distorted
\draw[spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-1cm}}];
% So if we redraw it with arrows it gets doubly shortened
\draw[->.>,spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-2cm}}];
% If we disable the shortening, the arrows end up in the right place
\draw[->.>,spath/use={arrow,transform={yshift=-3cm}}, spath/disable arrow shortening];
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

I am unsure why this problem appears here as well, since the path seems to be long enough. But the distortion at the end of the third path hints to a similar problem of path segments being too short. (With larger values for `radius` or by loading the `bending` library, the result is correct again.)

Comment: I think your analysis is right. Somehow the code remembers the original direction of the path even when it has been "inverted" by the shortening mechanism. I wonder if it is possible to reverse the direction of the arrow using arrow keys.